# Sending Array of object picked from DataTable, though Ajax to a Controller MVC error 400

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller, datatables

First time questioner here.
I am currently trying to learn a bit of using Datatables in MVC.
The problem i have is that i get error 400 when i try to send it to the controller.

I am quite new to Ajax and it so happens i have a little pickle sending the information i have lying in the datatable.
I have tried several solutions without avail and i am frankly not sure what it is that i am doing wrong.
First i have a javascript that collects the data from the Datatable, and using console.log it becomes an object array

```
function insertOrUpdate() {
        var update = [];


        $("#Table tbody tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Id = table.row(this).data()[4];
            var Designation = row.find("#txtDesignation").val();
            var TNumber = row.find("#txtTNumber").val();
            var OStorage = row.find("#txtOStorage").val();
            var SortNumber = row.find("TD").eq(0).text();
            var ObId = table.row(this).data()[5];

            update.push({
                Id: Id,
                Designation: Designation,
                TNumber: TNumber,
                OStorage: OStorage,
                SortNumber: SortNumber,
                ObId: ObId
            });
        });
```

The Ajax i have currently written looks like:

```
var postData = {"Object": update };

        addAntiForgeryToken(postData);
        addAntiForgeryToken();
        $.ajax({
        cache: false,
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.RouteUrl("UpdateOrInsert")',
            data: JSON.stringify(postData),
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (r) {
                alert(r + ' record(s) inserted.');
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert('Cannot update');
                 },
                 failure: function () {
                     alert('Cannot update');
                 }
        });
        }
```

I have created a Model in the model part of mvc, the BaseAppEntityModel simply have Id defined for reuseability:

```
public partial class InsertUpdateModel : BaseAppEntityModel
    {
        public string Designation { get; set; }     

    public string TNumber { get; set; }

    public string OStorage { get; set; }

    public string SortNumber { get; set; }

    public string ObId { get; set; }
}
```

As for the Controller itself i have tried several versions:

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult UpdateOrInsert(List<InsertUpdateModel> Object)
    {
        return Json(null);
    }
```

i have also tried:

```
[HttpPost]
        public void UpdateOrInsert(List<InsertUpdateModel> Object)
        {
            var t = Object;
        }
```

or

```
public virtual IActionResult UpdateOrInsert(List<UpdateOrInsert> Object)
        {
            return Json(null);
        }
```

I would be very greatful if anyone had a little time for my question as it seems I am not getting any headway on this, even doe I've spent the better part of a few days just trying different ways to make it work.

Edit: For clarification ill add another Ajax call that i have in the same view that works perfectly fine.

```
    var Id;
    var obId = @Model.Id;
    var arrayId = new Array();

function confirmSelectedDelete() {
           let rows = table.rows('.selected');
           Id = table.cells(rows.nodes(), [4]).data();

           for (var i = 0; i < Id.length; i++) {

               arrayId.push(Id[i]);

           }

         function sendDeleteToController() {

             var postData = {"Id": arrayId, "ObId": obId };

             addAntiForgeryToken(postData);
             addAntiForgeryToken();
             $.ajax({
                 cache: false,
                 type: 'POST',
                 url: '@Url.RouteUrl("Delete")',
                 data: postData,
                 dataType: 'json',
                 success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                     table.rows('.selected').remove().draw();
                 },
                 error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                     alert('Cannot remove');
                 },
                 failure: function () {
                     alert('Cannot remove');
                 }
             });
         };
         sendDeleteToController();
         emptyArray();
    };
```

and the controller have:

```
        [HttpPost]
    public virtual IActionResult Delete(string[] Id, string ObId)
    {
        string obId = ObId.Trim();
        List<string> listId = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in Id)
        {
            if (!StringHelper.AreNullOrEmpty(i))
                listId.Add(i.Trim());
        }
        if (listId.Count > 0)
            _service.Delete(listId, obId);

        return Json(null);
    }
```

This call works perfectly fine, but i don't understand why the first one doesn't work.

Comment: Use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to look at first request.  The 400 is the status in the response.  A good response would be 200 OK.  I suspect the 400 is occurring because it is a secure server using https and requires a certificate using SSL/TLS.

Comment: if i don't missunderstand the wireshark it starts off with POST /updateorinsert http/1.1 (application/json) and the response is http/1.1 400 bad request. does that help anything?

Comment: Http has two modes : A) 1.0 stream mode B) 1.1 chunk mode.  I do not think the mode has to do with issue.  The request is non secure http ( not https).  Error 400 indicates bad syntac.  You have to look at the headers in the request and see if they are correct.  If you have another application that works with same server compare the working with non working.  The http  sets default header that the server may not accept.  Like the server only works with Chrome and the default header for the browser is IE.  The browser is the Content-Type header.

Comment: i have another call that works with the same server and i have it on the same view. ill add it to the post for clarification.

Comment: Thank you jdweng, thanks to your questions it made me rethink what i did, and finally i managed to send the information to the controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By a happenstance and thanks to jdweng making me look back and reflect harder on the code i stumbeled upon the solution:

```
function loadAllInformation() {
        var update = [];

        $("#toolTable tbody tr").each(function () {
            var row = $(this);
            var Id = table.row(this).data()[4];
            var Designation = row.find("#txtDesignation").val();
            var TNumber = row.find("#txtTNumber").val();
            var ObStorage = row.find("#txtObStorage").val();
            var SortNumber = row.find("TD").eq(0).text();
            var ObId = table.row(this).data()[5];

            update.push({
                Id: Id,
                Designation: Designation,
                TNumber: TNumber,
                ObStorage: ObStorage,
                SortNumber: SortNumber,
                ObId: ObId
            });
        });
        function sendUpdateToController() {
            console.log(update);
            var postData = { "Object": update };
            addAntiForgeryToken(postData);
            addAntiForgeryToken();
            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.RouteUrl("UpdateOrInsert")',
                data: postData,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (r) {
                    alert(r + ' record(s) inserted.');
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                    alert('Cannot update');
                },
                failure: function () {
                    alert('Cannot update');
                }
            });
        };
        sendUpdateToController();
        emptyArray();
    };
```

and as for the controller it is:

```
  [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateOrInsert(List<InsertUpdateModel> Object)
    {
        foreach(var item in Object)
        {
            Console.Write(item.Id);
        }

        return Json(null);
    }
```

the foreach is just me confirming that information is actually getting pushed to the controller.

as for the model, it is the same as my question entry, hope this will help someone eventually.